# Slider cuts off [flex slider] with bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, slider

my slider cuts off and I noticed wwhat causing it is boostrap, the framework i use for the grid system.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/5q39A/1/
```

Why acutally does it cuts off? I included all css meaning with boostrap too.

this is the boostrap website: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

You can see the slider cuts off there:

```
http:// justxp.plutohost.net /survive/index.html
```

any help would be appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what is causing the issue:

```
li {
line-height: 18px;
margin: 5px;
}

on line 545 of bootstrap.css
```

Use this example to override:

Change this:

```
.flexslider .slides > li {
display: none;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

on line 327 of style.css
```

To this:

```
.flexslider .slides > li {
display: none;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
margin:0 !important;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5q39A/4/

Comment: Wow thanks! 
Can I ask a few questions? well only two.

What does margin 0 do?
also what does !important do?

and how can I add a 960px square background for the circles? thanks!

Comment: `margin:0;` removes any margins for the list item. and `!important` is an override for all other styles.this allows your `style.css` to override `bootstrap.css`